# Get a BigInt value from a resultset (Oracle db) in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to get a `BIGINT` value from Oracle database using JDBC.
`getBigInt()` or `getBigInteger()` does not work like `getInt()`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    try
    {
        //typical jdbc coding
        Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee1");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee(rs.getString("emp_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getBigInt("emp_mob"));
            employeeList.add(employee);
        }
        DBUtil.closeConnection(conn);  //close connection
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return employeeList;
}
```

> **emp_mob column in the table contains big integer values.**

Comment: What is the current exception? Not to your question, but you should be closing the `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in a `finally` block (or using a `try-with-resources`).

Comment: Perhaps try `getLong` or `getBigDecimal`

Comment: [Isn't bigint just a `long`?](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj30435.html)

Answer (score 8):

The `BIGINT` data type is an *8-byte binary number*, which means that the matching Java type is a **`long`**, so use [`getLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getLong-java.lang.String-):

```java
long mob = rs.getLong("emp_mob");
```

If the column is `NULL`-able, use Java type **`Long`**, and call [`wasNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull--) after calling `getLong()`:

```java
Long mob = rs.getLong("emp_mob");
if (rs.wasNull())
    mob = null;
```

Alternatively, if you want a Java [**`BigInteger`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), call [`getBigDecimal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal-java.lang.String-) and convert it:

```java
BigDecimal decimal = rs.getBigDecimal("emp_mob");
BigInteger mob = (decimal == null ? null : decimal.toBigInteger());
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is `.getObject(colIdx, BigInteger.class);`, but whether that'll actually work depends on your JDBC driver. It probably won't, but you should try it: If it does, there you go. Simple, efficient, no issues there.

If it doesn't, you should probably use `.getBigDecimal()`. This is another way that a JDBC driver might not actually support, so try it out.

If that's a failure too, your last real resort is `.getString`, and then pass that to BigInteger to reparse into a number. This is rather inefficient. What is the type of the column/expression in your SQL? It'd help to know, and that's a good place to search the docs.

Answer (score -2):

Use `BigInteger.valueOf(rs.getLong("emp_mob"))`
And this way is safer.

Comment: 'safer'? This will probably end up silently returning garbage for numbers that are too large. You'd think if someone asks about BigInteger they have a big integer.

Comment: what value of rs.getLong() will return a value too large for BigInteger.valueOf()?